# Programmatically placing code into a document.querySelector in a JavaScript/React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In JavaScript/React, I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically place code into a document.querySelector? For example, let's say I want the querySelector to find an element with the id #test123. Can I dynamically make it equal to `<span id="monitor_metric_1"></span>`?

What I tried: I know that it's possible to dynamically add text like this:
`document.querySelector('#test123').textContent = 'ON';`

But what I want to do is to insert an HTML element, like this:
`document.querySelector('#test123').textContent = '<span id="monitor_metric_1"></span>';`

However, this just adds the text and not the actual HTML element. Is there a more appropriate property to use instead of textContent to insert the HTML element into the target element?

Comment: Thats completely agains the React way. Don't use querySelector at all.

Comment: Doing it that way is a really bad idea, but on the other hand it has nothing to do with React. Unsurprisingly `textContent` sets the text content and HTML elements aren't text. If you really want to do it this way, look up how to set the HTML content of elements.

Comment: Well it's `.innerHTML`, but since you're using React you should not manipulate the DOM like that

Comment: why would you be doing this in a react app?

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I was exploring different approaches to understand the implications of using direct DOM manipulation in a React app, but I recognize that using React components and state management is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Directly manipulating the DOM using methods like querySelector and innerHTML, bypasses React's virtual DOM and therefore, also its optimizations. So, while it is possible, it is not preferred as it can introduce unexpected behavior or poor performance. The more correct approach would be to use React components and state to manage the application's UI.